# Comparing Times Using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I've been playing around with [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) and I've come across a problem.  I've been trying to identify whether a date given is in the past or in the future.  The dates are stored as [Unix timestamps](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/).  So when I'm comparing future dates with current dates, it's working ok, but it's not triggering for past dates.  The sample code is below and a [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/the_archer/b5pSn/3/).

```
var pastUnixTime = '1348812970'; //some time in the past
var futureUnixTime = '1352350231';

if (moment.unix(futureUnixTime).format('DD MM YYYY') > moment().format('DD MM YYYY')) {
    console.log('yay');
}


if (moment.unix(pastUnixTime).format('DD MM YYYY') < moment().format('DD MM YYYY')) {
    console.log('yay 2');
}
​
```

The above code logs `yay` not not `yay 2`.  Can anybody explain to me why is it not logging `yay 2`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You actually don't need to use `.format()` at all for this.

First, the timestamps should be numbers, not strings (ex, `var pastUnixTime = 1348812970;`), and second, you can compare them directly:

```
> pastUnixTime = 1348812970;
> pastUnixTime < moment().unix()
true
> pastUnixTime > moment().unix() 
false
```

Now, the reason your code is failing is that when you compare the `DD MM YYYY` strings, they are being compared lexicographically… And the days are *first*! So the string `"01 01 2000"` will always be "less than" `"31 12 1900"`. If you *wanted* to compare strings, you could use `YYYY MM DD` format — that way, `"2000 01 01"` will be correctly "greater than" `"1900 12 31"`. But there's no reason to do that - timestamps are much more straight forward.

Finally, a note: you don't actually need to use the `.unix()` - instances of `moment()` will compare sensibly:

```
> past = moment().subtract("days", 1)
> now = moment()
> past < now
true
> past > now
false
```

Comment: yes, but the only reason I'm formatting them is I want to know if the timestamp older than the current day or newer.  A timestamp may not be same as current timestamp given by moment() but still be in same day, which would not indicate that it's in the past. EDIT: I hope I'm not too confusing :$

Comment: fantastic - thank you - the problem was the lexicographical comparison.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't notice that. There are two ways you could fix that: either compare the strings (see my comment) *or* use `.startOf("day")`: `moment.unix(…).startOf("day") < moment().startOf("day")`. IMO the latter is much clearer, as it makes your intention very obvious.

Comment: no problem :) Also, see my last edit about not even needing to use `.unix()`.

Comment: @DavidWolever: regarding your final note. i noticed that as well, and was wondering, googled why it is like that, and found this thread. can you explain why it is? inspecting the source of moment.js, moment() should just return an object!?

Comment: @hereandnow78 the object returned by `moment()` implements a [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) method, which JavaScript uses when making comparisons.