# Date Comparison Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two date strings in `DDMMYYYY` format. say `startdate="18/02/2013"` and `enddate ="26/02/2013"`.

How can I compare these dates. I want `enddate` to be greater than or equal to `startdate`
Thanks for Your Time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse

Comment: Use [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com) and be happy.

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264457/comparing-times-using-moment-js

Comment: Also check [date](http://www.datejs.com/) library.

Comment: I'll suggest you to stay away from libraries for simple tasks like this.

Comment: There's absolutely no need for a library to do something as easy as this.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh While it's interesting to do this by hand once, I'll use moment.js for this any day (just as I use jQuery.xhr over XMLHttpRequest anyday). I get to pick my tools. Go tools! The reason for using a better refined API becomes much more "clear" when considering that it's very easy to *visualize* what is occurring: `moment.parse(theString, "DD/MM/YYYY")` (also notice that this made it easy to identify the error with the stated MMDDYYY format).

Comment: Thanks all. @wared I meant DDMMYYYY

Comment: I have added a demo. Please don't pay attention to the "-1", my answer has been hit by the mad downvoter :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a fan of [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and consider it a core part of my toolkit whenever I have to deal with dates and times - *especially* when any form of parsing or formatting is involved.

You're free to do the parsing by hand and invoke the appropriate Date constructor manually, but consider the following which I consider simple and intuitive.

```
var startDate = moment.parse("18/02/2013", "DD/MM/YYYY");
var endDate = moment.parse("26/02/2013", "DD/MM/YYYY");

if (endDate.isAfter(startDate)) {
   // was after ..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this solution suits your needs (demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/MdA3B/)?

```
var startdate = '18/02/2013';
var d1 = startdate.split('/');
d1 = new Date(d1.pop(), d1.pop() - 1, d1.pop());

var enddate = '26/02/2013';
var d2 = enddate.split('/');
d2 = new Date(d2.pop(), d2.pop() - 1, d2.pop());

if (d2 >= d1) {
    // do something
}
```

Keep in mind that months begin with 0. [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) :

> month : Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

Comment: General code suggestions: 1) avoid resuing the same variable name for different purposes; 2) *avoid* side-effects in function call arguments (indexing would likely be be apt here); 3) use small functions liberally - http://jsfiddle.net/9Qeye/2/

Comment: @user2864740 Well, after the shameless cheater and the mad downvoter, here comes the bombastic teacher :D Hey, it's a joke, I'm just tired to debate over obviousnesses. Thanks for your precious advices.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d1 = Date.parse("18/02/2013");
var d2 = Date.parse("26/02/2013");
if (d1 > d2) {
  alert ("do something");
}
```

Comment: `Date.parse("18/02/2013")` results in NaN here. I'm not exactly sure what format(s) `Date.parse` *should* parse and I avoid it because I don't know what the specification says on the matter or what browser/localization quirks exists. (Locally, it appears to parse `Date.parse("02/18/2013")` correctly. Go [United Sates dates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)!)