# How to compare current time with JSON data

Tags: angularjs

I have JSON data as below:

```
[
{
 "morning":"5:36 am",
 "evening":"7:00 pm"
}
]
```

I want to compare JSON data with current time. Ex: is morning > current time ?

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in schedule">
<div>Morning - {{item.morning}}</div>
<div>Eveing - {{item.evening}}</div>
</div>
```

I have specified the AngularJS part to display the Data and It's working. Now I want to compare the **{{item.morning}}** with **current time** and display a message in front of **{{item.morning}}** as "Time up" based on condition.

Please let me know how can I compare time in AngularJS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing Times Using Moment.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264457/comparing-times-using-moment-js) - Not really a direct duplicate but pretty much - trust me use Moment.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PWKad mentioned, you should use a date library like moment.js.
One reason for that, might be that trying to implement it yourself can end with an ugly, quick-and-(really)-diry code like this:

Controller:

```
      $scope.isTimeUp = function(time) {
          var hour, minute;
          if(time.split(" ")[1] == 'pm' && time.split(":")[0] != '12') {
              hour = parseInt(time.split(":")[0]) + 12;
          } else {
              hour = parseInt(time.split(":")[0]);
          }
          minute = parseInt(time.split(":")[1]);

          var today = new Date();
          var givenDate = new Date();
          givenDate.setHours(hour);
          givenDate.setMinutes(minute);

          if(givenDate < today) {
              return true;
          } else {
              return false;
          }

      }
```

html:

```
    <div ng-repeat="item in schedule">
        <div>
            Morning - {{item.morning}}
            <span ng-if="isTimeUp(item.morning)">
                Time's up!
            </span>
        </div>
        <div>
            Eveing - {{item.evening}}
            <span ng-if="isTimeUp(item.evening)">
                Time's up!
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

...and this is following your markup. You might want to implement a custom filter instead. But again, use moment.js.

Anyways, it seems to be working, though I haven't put much thought in it or tested it too much - [see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9xnfL/19/).

Comment: Thanks @Kludge, This really helped. I am looking into moment.js documentation. I will surelt use both to get an understanding of how it works.

Comment: Hi @Kludge, I updated the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9xnfL/20/)   , since the 12:35 pm was considered as next day with your logic. I added if(time.split(" ")[1] == 'pm' && time.split(":")[0] != '12') in the condition

Comment: @user2218497, lol, 10x. We don't use 12-hour clock in my country :P